# How to add the 'upstream try' to the request which I send to the backend server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an nginx server which acts as a load balancer.

The nginx is configured to upstream 3 tries:
`proxy_next_upstream_tries 3`

I am looking for a way to pass to the backend server the current try number of this request - i.e. first, second or last.

I believe it can be done by passing this data in the header, however, how can I configure this in nginx and where can I take this data from?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, Nginx does not provide such information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent this question to Nginx support and they provided me this explanation:

> As long as you are using proxy_next_upstream mechanism for 
>   retries, what you are trying to do is not possible.  The request 
>   which is sent to next servers is completely identical to the one 
>   sent to the first server nginx tries - or, more precisely, this is the 
>   same request, created once and then sent to different upstream 
>   servers as needed.
>   If you want to know on the backend if it is handling the first 
>   request or it processes a retry request after an error, a working 
>   option would be to switch proxy_next_upstream off, and instead 
>   retry requests on 502/504 errors using the error_page directive.
>   See http://nginx.org/r/error_page for examples on how to use 
>   error_page.

So, I did as they advised me:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;

location / {
     proxy_pass http://example.com;
     proxy_set_header NlbRetriesCount 0;
     error_page 502 404 @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
     proxy_pass http://example.com;
     proxy_set_header NlbRetriesCount 1;
}
```